# Dropbox access token questions

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm currently using the dropbox api, and got some doubts about oauth access token:

1. Does the access token expire?
2. I just need to save the access token, or I need something else? (authorization token, user id...)
3. What happens if I lose the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, Dropbox API access tokens don't expire by themselves, but they can be revoked by the user or app at any time.
2. You only need an access token to make API calls for the linked user, but you may also wish to save more information, such as a user ID, depending on the needs of your app. (E.g., for keeping track of which access token corresponds to which account, etc.)
3. If you lose the access token, or it is revoked, you'd need to prompt the user to process the OAuth app authorization flow again to get a new one if they wish to continue using the Dropbox integration.